# Repeat a 3 second loop 10x in a 30 second video

Tags: macos, video, motion

I have a short sequence loop in Motion 5. The file loops for 3 seconds, but my video is 30 seconds in length.

I want to repeat the short sequence file 10 times, so it fits the 30 seconds.

The only way I found to do this is to stretch it, but then it plays 10x slower.
I don't want the speed to be slower. I am just trying to keep the loop on repeat for 30 seconds on normal speed, but there is no button for repeat to do this. Maybe it is hidden somewhere and I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the three second clip ten times in a row. The fastest way to do this is with keyboard shortcuts and the insertion point moves along as you paste.

Comment: hey thanks for fast answer , but this does not work properly.
because in this way it creates new channels in the timeline , and i will end up with 10 channels on top of each other in the timeline. can you just imagine hundreds of channels there ? so that is not the good way to do it. there should be an easy way to have all files on 1 channel only .  anyone knows how to do this  ? thanks :)  - posted for @elmentor by IconDaemon.